# SharePoint Online Get Authentication token without redirecting to URL

Tags: oauth-2.0, botframework, sharepoint-online

I have a ChatBot using Microsoft Bot Framework which is hosted on azure which gets data from a SharePoint list and displays the same. This chatbot is used in SharePoint page.

When used first types in message, bot responds with address of URL clicking on which returns the access token which can be used to authenticate with SharePoint. Format of URL is as below:

```
{spAuth_SiteUri}/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?client_id={spAuth_AppClientId}&redirect_uri={spAuth_RedirectUri}
```

Is there any way we can bypass this redirection and get token from back end? Method which is used is below:

```
GetClientContextWithContextToken
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Add-ins are authenticated against the SharePoint host. You could create an add-in which itself hosts the webchat client.  You can/could tweak web-chat to do additional stuff with SharePoint as needed from there. This would be opposed to the simple webchat in an iframe/webpart setup (which won't let you do what you need).

Please see the following links for more information.

[SharePoint Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-add-ins)

[WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)